Could someone in the Old Testament be saved without believing in Christ?
I have often heard it taught that those living in the time of the Old Testament were saved by the law, but that they also had to have faith that Christ would come. If someone living in the Old Testament era did not believe that Christ would come and denied the future coming of the Messiah, could they still be saved? Or was belief in the future coming of Christ necessary for salvation in that time period?

At all times people must trust in the person of God and in the message he has revealed. In ancient times he had revealed less details of his great plan for salvation, but whatever he had revealed is what he expected people to trust.

In other words, what was the actual content of the faith of the "men of faith" listed in Hebrews ch11?

Belief in and of itself does not save anyone (James 2:14). The significance of belief is that it guides our actions - and by acting accordingly we can be saved. Ultimately we are not judged on our doctrines, but upon how we live our lives.

This is a common question, and it's quite politically incorrect or controversial that such topics gets closed. Was eternal life promised by the Mosaic Law?

@RyanPierceWilliams If we are judged by how we live our lives there would be no need for Jesus Christ to die on the cross for our salvation. Who taught you this? Are you a Unitarian? People in the Old Testament were saved the same way as those in the New Testament, through faith alone, by grace alone, and in Christ alone. Paul explains this at Romans 4. Abraham believed God and it was reckoned to him as righteousness. Please read the whole chapter and also read Hebrews 11:1.

@Mr.Bond The scriptures are quite explicit that eternal life is the reward for pursuing a good, righteous life (example: Romans 2:6-11). Jesus taught that you must give your life to save it (Matthew 16:25). It is not sufficient to cry “Lord, Lord” to be saved - for Jesus will reject you before his father and say that he does not know you. On the other hand, he will raise up and reward those who help the least of these. So then, we observe this truth: that through our loving actions we make God known to others, and through those we bless we in turn become known to God.

So you deem Christ dying on that cross for nothing? He's sacrifice was to atone for humanity's sins and restore the relationship between God and humanity. This is described at 2 Corinthians 5:21. By trying to live a good life and doing good things won't cut it. How are you going to live up to Romans 3:23 since we all without exception fall short of the glory of God?

@Mr.Bond I most certainly did not say that Christ's death was somehow irrelevant to salvation. You are the one making the false deduction that if works are involved then that somehow invalidates the grace we recieve through Christ. Scripture teaches both grace and works, together. The parable of the Unforgiving Servant (Matthew 18:21-35) illustrates this point nicely. The servant is forgiven a large debt. However, this forgiveness is revoked when he himself does not forgive a much smaller debt. However, if he had forgiven that small debt - would that have earned him his forgiveness? No.

These are your words. "Ultimately we are not judged on our doctrines, but upon how we live our lives." And btw, yes we are judged on our doctrines/what we believe. Paul explained this at Galatians 1:6-9 and at other places. Matthew 7:15-23 where Jesus is speaking. The four most lethal words in the Bible is at Matthew 7:23 where Jesus says, "I never knew you " Read Matthew 7. From reading your post you really struck me as being "naive." You better believe Jesus means business. I am not using scare tactics, just telling you the truth. Please read John 3:16.

Those are my words - but you demonstrate that you don't understand them. Belief without works are dead and cannot save you - as taught in James 2. You are ignoring all of scripture for a couple lines from Paul that you demonstrate you don't understand. Paul himself taught that eternal life is the reward for good deeds in Romans 2. He advocates perseverance, lest you fall short and lose the prize (eternal life). Worst of all is that you ignore Christ's own words on the matter: you must lose your life to save it. It is foolish to think that holding the right doctrines is how Jesus knows you.

@Mr.Bond If you want to know who Christ knows and acknowledges before God, then see the parable of the sheep and goats. They are not distinguished by their doctrines, but by their good deeds towards the least of these.

@RyanPierceWilliams There is no contradiction between Paul and James. For example, when Abraham was 100 and Sara 90 years old, Abraham believed God would fulfill His promise. At James 2:21 taught that Abraham's obedience in offering Isaac at Genesis 22. (As a side note Abraham offered Isaac to the angel of the Lord, read Genesis 22.) The context makes it clear that James taught a person is justified by the kind of faith which is genuine and RESULTS in obedience. This is how Paul and James are reconciled. This is Biblical doctrine/teaching that result on how we live our lives. Pay attention!

@Mr.Bond I never asserted there was a contradiction - but rather I pointed out to you that Paul says the same: that eternal life, the promise, is a reward for good deeds. You are ignoring a great wealth of scripture, including Christ's direct teachings.

This statement of yours is a contradiction of what the Bible teaches.  "Ultimately we are not judged on our doctrines, but upon how we live our lives." And you just said, " that eternal life, the promise, is a reward for good deeds." Eternal life is based on Jesus dying on that cross and putting your faith in Him. upon doing that you will do good deeds. This is what Paul and James taught. The thief on the cross did not do good deeds and Jesus told him he would be in Paradise that day with Jesus. At Acts 10:43-44, Peter was giving the house of Cornelius (a Roman soldier) the gospel. Cont.

Cont. and at Acts 10:45 Cornelius received the gift of the Holy Spirit and was saved in that instant. AFTER he received the Holy Spirt Peter had him water baptized. This also means that baptism is not a requirement for salvation. He did not do any good works to get saved, because one who is saved will do good works, see 2 Corinthians 5:17. My last two comments. "Ultimately" is defined as "finally, in the end. conclusion." Secondly, since you deny the deity of Jesus Christ your good works will not save you, only faith in Jesus Christ. Isaiah 64;6, Your works are like filthy rags.

@Mr.Bond I have provided numerous NT scriptures - from Paul, from James, from Jesus in the Gospels - that explicitly state that eternal life is the reward for good deeds. You are simply turning a blind eye to the scriptures that clearly contradict you. I'm afraid further discussion here is pointless - you've made it clear that what you care about is your doctrines and not the truth of scripture.

Fine, your free to do want you want. But remember, for me this is not about "doctrines." It's about where your going to spend eternity, in short, I care!

Faith in the Messiah, and repentance towards God is the only way of salvation, and always has been.
Adam and Eve were given the promise of a future Messiah as soon as they sinned:

And I will put enmity between you and the woman, and between your offspring and hers; he will crush your head, and you will strike his heel, Genesis 3:15.

It was faith in Christ through believing this promise that brought salvation to all who believed it.  A further act signifying that this future Messiah would be a substitutionary sacrifice for sin was demonstrated by the killing of an animal and the provision of a covering from the skin of the sacrifice.  There included in this faith which saved an acknowledgment by the believer that his/her sins deserved death.  Cain refused to believe this and sacrificed only vegetables;  Abel agreed with it and sacrificed the best of his flock.
One of the earliest books in the Bible reveals the faith in Christ that was possible before Christ was born:

For I know that my Redeemer lives, and at the last he will stand upon the earth.  And after my skin has been thus destroyed, yet in my flesh I shall see God, whom I shall see for myself, and my eyes shall behold, and not another. My heart faints within me!  Job 19:25-27.

Job expresses his confidence in his resurrection, and that his saviour will not be the invisible God, but a kinsman redeemer, both God and man.  All the OT prophets were saved because of their faith in the coming Messiah.
The moral law and the ten commandments were never given in order to save anyone, merely to demonstrate how impossible it is to please God by our own attempts, now that we are a fallen race.

Can the devil have an offspring? Certainly not but Eve can so that is ruled out because God was technically talking about the literal snake which can have offspring

@SoFewAgainstSoMany - both the literal snake and that ancient serpent who is called Satan and the Devil (Revelation 12:9) are being referred to. Satan has his spiritual children, all the demonic spirits, all the demons who follow him, and all the human race who have not God as their father and who follow Satan: you are of your father the devil (John 8:44).

Only a created human being or an animal can have an offspring and God, angels can't and that is why the devil needed to possess that animal to get his message across because all spirit angels are invisible to the naked human eye, it's like the Balaam story where a donkey talked

@SoFewAgainstSoMany - why are you insisting that God is talking about physical/biological offspring????? in Genesis 3:15

Because the devil is invisible to the naked human eye for he is spirit. Can you see the devil right now? If you cannot see the devil, why would you think Eve saw him in the garden ?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany - because he entered into a serpent

Galatians 3:24 "Wherefore the law was our schoolmaster to bring us unto Christ, that we might be justified by faith."

@AndrewShanks, exactly, you've understood, great

@SoFewAgainstSoMany - What have I understood?  Who doubts there is a double meaning to Genesis 3:15; the trivial meaning is it refers to physical snakes, the real meaning is it refers to that ancient serpent who us called Satan and the Devil.  I really don't know what point you are trying to make.

You just deleted your earlier comment and made me blind, Thanks so much

@SoFewAgainstSoMany - I don't remember deleting anything.  What did the "deleted comment" say?

The Israelites of the Old Covenant established between God and the Israelites at Mount Sinai with Moses as the witness required them to observe the Torah,to be clean and to observe the ten commandments.
I have read the Bible several times from Genesis to Judges and it is difficult to see the Messianic prophecies. The Messianic prophecies started to emerge with prophets like Jeremiah, Isaiah and others. It is difficult to believe in a figure that has not been born yet for your salvation, I was shocked that some Christians here believe that Adam had to believe in Jesus whom he didn't know for his salvation, so be wary of false teachers and false doctrines. Trust the Bible only and not the interpretation  of man.
I can give you an array of prophets who went to heaven and didn't believe in Jesus, we start with Enoch who walked with God, God reportedly took him alive, then there is Elijah,then there is Elisha and the list is endless till Jesus was born.
We believe in Jesus because his gospel and his ministry have been preached to us and we have heard and believed, but it was not possible to preach the gospel of Jesus Christ to people who lived before he was born including Israelites for Jesus needed to rise from the dead first to show us God's plan for this age.

I didn't -1 your answer.  I agree that reading the OT figures would've seen messianic prophecies as we do today.  You said "an array of prophets who went to heaven and didn't believe in Jesus, we start with Enoch ... "  But wouldn't it be more accurate instead of saying "didn't believe" to say that although they wasn't aware of Jesus's full mission centuries/millenia later, they would have believed in Jesus when they meet him in heaven?  Remember how positively the writer of Hebrews portray the "heroes of faith" in Heb 11, including Enoch?

@GratefulDisciple, the name Jesus was given after he conquered death, sin , the devil and the world. He received authority after he rose from the dead, after he ascended to the Father, during the Old Testament he didn't have that authority

"I can give you an array of prophets who went to heaven" —  only if by "heaven" you mean up into the Earth's atmosphere.  If you mean God's spiritual abode, consider John 3:13: "And no man hath ascended up to heaven, but he that came down from heaven, even the Son of man which is in heaven."; and Acts 2:29 where Peter says "… the patriarch David, that he is both dead and buried, and his sepulchre is with us unto this day.", not "David is with God in Heaven".

@RayButterworth, sure even Elijah went to the atmosphere with a chariot of fire

@StephenDisraeli's apt rephrasing of your question is "In other words, what was the actual content of the faith of the "men of faith" listed in Hebrews 11"?
Many Christians maintain that those men of faith would have believed in Christ when they meet Jesus in heaven. It's reasonable to assume that God would judge every OT person according to how they would react to what God has revealed so far in their lifetime.  As long as one didn't reject what God revealed so far, didn't rebel in their conscience, and obeyed the prompting to seek God (Prov 28:4-5), not knowing the details on how the salvation was going to come in God's incarnation in Jesus shouldn't be counted against them.
Of course the prophet Jeremiah's and the prophet Isaiah's content of faith was a lot more than what Abraham had, let alone Adam and Noah, because Jeremiah and Isaiah had the benefit of God's revelation at Sinai, the history of Israel's many rescues, the role model of David in his relationship with God, and other prophecies prior to their time.  So people in both prophets' time should have been more sure of God's future salvation, even though God had not revealed fully the manner of His salvation through Christ.  They only possessed hints such as Job 19:25-27, Abraham's trusting God to save Isaac because God promised him a great nation as descendants, Israelites' trusting God to settle them in Canaan, David's believing God for the future fulfillment of God's promise that his kingdom would endure forever, etc.
No one would have predicted that God would come in person face to face (even the disciples on the road to Emmaus needed Jesus to explain it to them), but the criteria should be how they would respond in faith to the content of faith given to them, rather than their ability to typologically interpret definitively the prophecies that the Messiah would appear as the eternal King descendant of David, as the "son of man" (Daniel 7:13-14), as a "suffering servant" (Isaiah 53), etc. in the person of God-crucified in Christ.  Most of them didn't even have the benefit of the critical prophecy recorded in the book of Daniel!
Similarly, we in the New Testament era also have limited "content of faith" especially when the Second Coming of Christ seems to be delayed further and further, and how God can seem absent in the face of growing global awareness of grievous injustice and oppression to the weak in modern-day human trafficking and how war agressors seem act with impunity against civilians.  The story of humanity-saving project of God is ongoing and we Christians are invited to take part, not only in spreading the gospel but also to bring God's justice and compassion to greater areas of the earth today.
The key criteria common to everyone past, present, and future is: when you meet Christ at the door as you pass from this life to the next (wonderfully portrayed in C.S. Lewis's final chapters of The Last Battle) would you rejoice to find in the face of Jesus what you have been longing for as you seek God your entire life, or would you recoil to find the clearest expression of what you have been hating and avoiding your entire life?
Finally, "saved by the law" is a Pauline concept foreign to OT people.  They would have understood "faith in God" as doing their part in being faithful to God's covenant, partly by doing the "works of the law" which was not identical to simply doing good by the light of faith they possess in responding to the "content of faith" they had received.
CONCLUSION: No, they can only be saved by believing in Christ, but to OT people Christ would be revealed fully to them only when they died.  A Biblical hint is Christ preaching to souls in Hades (1 Pet 3:18-20) and how Matthew portrayed that the "saints were raised" (Matt 27:52).  Not being aware of Christ's mission to die on the cross to pay for their sins does not mean they don't "have faith that Christ would come".  Their faith in God would have been counted as faith in Christ, following the principle in Romans 4:3 with regards to Abraham.

When Jesus told the disciples if ye have seen me , ye have seen the father, he meant to support the other verse in the Pauline epistles that state the Son who has been at the bossom of the Father, has made him known, Jesus is the image of the invisible God, Jesus and God are unique individuals and this can be attested to the fact that they had a conversation where God said I have glorified it and will glorify it again

@SoFewAgainstSoMany I understand there are different teachings, but for Chalcedonian Trinitarians, Jesus and God are NOT unique individuals but 2 distinct relations (each relation is called "Person") within the single monotheistic Trinitarian God.  The 2nd relation ("The Son", the image) is the only one made manifest with flesh and blood in the temporal universe (being born at a certain date in the form of baby Jesus) while the 1st relation ("God the Father") remains in Eternity and is always Spirit (no body).  See my other answer.

Jesus in his human nature flesh talks with God.  It's the human flesh who died and resurrected by the Father, who was then glorified and sitting at the right hand of the Father.  Jesus is forever retaining his human body (the first to be glorified in the flesh) so in our own future glorified bodies we will still see Jesus face to face.

I believe God is One and it is the light spirit sited on the Throne of Eternity(Great White Throne), Jesus is sited at the right hand of God not on The Great White Throne, those two verses satisfy my desire on the identity of Jesus , even the Psalmist said The Lord said to my Lord, sit at my right hand till I make your enemies your footstool

But if he is sited at the right hand of God then the proximity of a hand to the Throne means Jesus is sharing the Throne of God with The Father. Which means the glory is One

@SoFewAgainstSoMany I would say the language of "sitting at the right hand of God" has many other connotations than a simple human-only language that another being is sitting next to you.  We also don't need to require the bodies of the enemies becoming a real footstool of Jesus.  The best understanding is how the human body of Jesus (the second Adam) was raised victorious and will visibly defeated the enemies (both spiritual angels and bad humans).  The Great White Throne is spiritual and symbolized as a Great White Throne.

The Great White Throne is real and not symbolic, it will come down together with the New Jerusalem after God creates a new heaven and a new earth, Daniel says Thrones we're set in heaven and the Ancient of Days whose hair was white as wool judged the nations.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany This comment thread is getting long and becomes out of policy because we are debating content, not about improving the answer.  You and I disagree with how to interpret certain Bible verses (which is extremely common), but this is not the place to discuss.  So I will stop responding.

The problem here is that salvation in the New Testament means something different from what it means in the Old Testament. In Paul's writing, salvation means the process by which a sinful person is justified before God through belief in the atoning sacrifice of Jesus. It is the means by which a person attains eternal life, and thereby saved from death, which is the "wages of sin."
Salvation in the OT has several meanings. It can mean being saved from ones enemies (who have the upper hand due to the petitioner's sin), from sickness (due do sin), from despair (also due to sin), from an impure heart, or from guilt. Although atonement was sometimes made through a sacrificial offering, salvation often happens directly. God forgives the repentant sinner, thereby delivering from from  their sin with no mediator. We find this often in the Psalms.
Psalm 18

The cords of Sheol encircled me;
the snares of death lay in wait for me. 7 In my distress I called out: Lord!
I cried out to my God. From his temple he heard my voice;
my cry to him reached his ears... He reached down from on high and seized me;
drew me out of the deep waters. 18 He rescued me from my mighty enemy,
from foes too powerful for me.

Other examples include:

Return, O Lord, deliver my soul! O save me for Thy mercies’ sake! (Psalm 6)

2 Bow down Thine ear to me, deliver me speedily; be Thou my strong rock, a house of defense to save me... 23 O love the Lord, all ye His saints! For the Lord preserveth the faithful... 24 Be of good courage, and He shall strengthen your heart, all ye that hope in the Lord.


Here and elsewhere, the psalmist is saved by God's loving-kindness. No mediator is involved. But in the NT, the mediation of Christ is essential. This can be explained by the fact that in Pauline soteriology, the sinful state is no momentary situation of despair but something basic in human nature. God often saved people from the consequences of their individual or collective sins in the OT. But he did not yet save them from sin in the general sense - what Christians call "original sin." (Psalm 31)
